# How to join where duplicates are needed?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table structure like this

Table1

```
PersonID, referrer
```

Table2

```
Event_A_ID, PersonID, status
```

Table3

```
Event_B_ID, PersonID, status
```

I want to get the event status for everyone from table one with `referrer=X` by joining all of the event tables like `Event_A...K` and checking for PersonID. Since people can appear in multiple events we can have cases like this

```
PersonID=1001, EventA_ID, referrer=X, status
PersonID=1001, EventB_ID, referrer=X, status
PersonID=1001, EventK_ID, referrer=X, status
PersonID=1002, ...
PersonID=1003, ...
```

But I am not sure how to JOIN all of the event tables since the IDs can be duplicates (and are desired).

I tried to make a separate select and use the `in` syntax

```
...
WHERE 1=1
AND PersonID IN (SELECT PersonID from table1 where referrer=X)
```

But then I realized everything before will be an aggregate of events.

Should I start with the SELECT from Table1? Select the valid IDs first and then select from the events after? If so, how do I JOIN? I feel like ideal looks like union of all the event tables and then select

Comment: Consider whether tables 2 & 3 should really be separate. Anyway, you can squish them together with UNION ALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `union all` and then apply `join`

```
select a.person_id,a.referrer,b.eventID,b.PersonID,b.status from Table1 a inner join
(
select Event_A_ID as eventID, PersonID, status from Table2
union all
select Event_B_ID as eventID, PersonID, status from Table3
)b on a.personid=b.personid
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use union all for row wise implementation of data or you can also use inner joins between tables if there is not much table events. This will represent data in column format.

```
SELECT * FROM tb2 AS t2 INNER JOIN tb3 t3 ON t2.personId = t3.personId INNER JOIN tb1 t1 ON t1.personId = t2.personId WHERE t1.refer='refer1'
```

There can be many other approach too depending on the number of tables you want to join.

You should also consider to use a better relations among your db tables as your current scenario will lead you to have as many tables as many events you have. This will create slowness in retrieving the data for multiple events.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with left joins:

```
SELECT t1.PersonID, t1.referrer, 
t2.Event_A_ID, t2.status as status_a, 
t3.Event_B_ID, t3.status as status_b
.
.
.
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.PersonID = t1.PersonID
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.PersonID = t1.PersonID
.
.
.
WHERE t1.referrer = 'x'
```

Comment: this is what i tried but it doesn't work for what I want

Comment: May you please send complete database structure with sample data?